# Dúvida em relação a existência de um "if" no código

Tags: javascript, node.js, if

Enunciado da questão: Construa uma função que receberá duas Strings de tamanhos variados e que retornará True ou False caso todos os caracteres (independentemente de ser maiúsculo ou minúsculo) estejam contidos em ambas palavras.

Resposta:

```
function verificacaoDeString (string1, string2) {
    let estaContido = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < string1.length; i++) {
        let caractereString1 = string1.charAt(i).toLowerCase()
        for(let j = 0; j < string2.length; j++){
            let caractereString2 = string2.charAt(j).toLowerCase()
            if(caractereString1 == caractereString2) {
                estaContido = true
                break
            } else {
                estaContido = false
            }
        }
        if(!estaContido) {
            return estaContido
        }
    }
    return estaContido
 }
```

Minha dúvida é o pq da existência desse trecho :

```
if(!estaContido) {
            return estaContido
        }
```

Peço desculpas pela ignorância, mas também peço a compreensão de vcs por eu ainda ser um iniciante no mundo de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Isso me parece um "early-return". Isso é, se o `for` interno falhar (note, existem dois `for`), então não há porque continuar iterando. Isso provalvelment também pode ser trocado por `if(!estaContido) { break }`, já que no final você ja dá um `return estaContido`. Mas, enfim, no final ambos cumprem o mesmo proposito: parar o loop no primeiro erro, ao invés de continuar.

Answer (score 2):

Existem dois `for`, um dentro do outro:

```
   // For do `string1`
   for (let i = 0; i < string1.length; i++) {
        let caractereString1 = string1.charAt(i).toLowerCase()

        // For do `string2`
        for(let j = 0; j < string2.length; j++){
            let caractereString2 = string2.charAt(j).toLowerCase()
            if(caractereString1 == caractereString2) {
                estaContido = true
                 
                // Se estiver contido: interrompe o "For do string2"
                break
            } else {
                estaContido = false
            }
        }
        
        // Se não estiver contido, não há porque continuar com o "For do string1".
        if(!estaContido) {
            // O return retornará a função imediatamente.
            return estaContido
        }
   }
```

Para cada letra do `string1` irá executar um novo `for`, este sendo o "For do String2". O "For do String2" define como "estaContido = false" se não houver a letra e definirá como "estaContido = true" se houver e também fará um "break" para interromper o "For do string2" (mas ainda continuará rodando o "For do String1").

Se o resultado é "estaContido = false", naõ há porque o "For do string1" continuar rodando, já que uma letra já falhou.

A questão que menciona explica que: "True ou False caso todos os caracteres". Se um caractere já é diferente, porque você vai continuar? Se um for diferente, já retorna imediatamente. ;)

---

Ignorei o fato da "Resposta" não fazer o que pediu (ele só valida o string1 contra o string2, não o inverso). Me restringi em tentar explicar o tal `if`. Mas... Não utilizo tanto Javascript, mas parentemente você pode usar o `Set`, passar para um Array, utilizar o Sort e então comparar os dois como string:

```
function verificacaoDeString (string1, string2) {
return [...new Set([...string1])].sort().join("") === [...new Set([...string2])].sort().join("");
}
```

*Isso resolve tal questão, *aparentemente*.*